# Can I use my azure DNS zone in more than one AKS clusters

Tags: azure, kubernetes, dns, azure-aks, azure-dns

I have DNS zone with my domain name and also I have an AKS cluster. I want to create dev and staging environments with two separate clusters. So I want to use same domain with different subdomains in each cluster and integrate it in ingress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like [Exposing Applications on Azure](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html).

So the idea is to use `External DNS` + `nginx ingress controller`.
You

- [Create 2 AKS clusters](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#create-aks-cluster)
- [Create 2 DNS zones entries](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#create-dns-zone-entry)

```
az group create -n devresourcegroup -l yourlocation
az network dns zone create -g devresourcegroup -n dev.yourdomainname.com

az group create -n stagingresourcegroup -l yourlocation
az network dns zone create -g stagingresourcegroup -n staging.yourdomainname.com
```

- [create](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#create-dns-zone-entry)  dev.yourdomainname.com and staging.yourdomainname.com entries
- [add permissions to modify dns zone for external-dns](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#add-permissions-to-modify-dns-zone)
- [deploy externaldns in both clusters](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#deploy-external-dns)

I **suppose** `external-dns-values.yaml` should be like

`dev-external-dns-values.yaml`:

```
domainFilters:
  - dev.yourdomainname.com          # (optional) Just restrict to this                     
...
azure:
  secretName: azure-config-file     # Secret name created above for dev
extraArgs:
  azure-resource-group: devresourcegroup  # (Optional) Resource group name created above
```

`staging-external-dns-values.yaml`:

```
domainFilters:
  - staging.yourdomainname.com     # (optional) Just restrict to this domain
...                 
azure:
  secretName: azure-config-file     # Secret name created above for staging
extraArgs:
  azure-resource-group: stagingresourcegroup  # (Optional) Resource group name created above
```

- Install [external-dns](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#deploy-external-dns)'es

```
helm install stable/external-dns --name external-dns -f dev-external-dns-values.yaml
helm install stable/external-dns --name external-dns -f staging-external-dns-values.yaml
```

- [Install Ingress controllers](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#deploy-nginx-ingress)
- [deploy apps](https://playbook.stakater.com/content/processes/exposing/azure-cluster-with-aws-subdomain.html#deploying-application) with proper ingress objects in each cluster. I mean this part

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: 
          servicePort: 
        path:
```